# How to trigger a button action without pressing it with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, action, eventtrigger

I'm using flutter for my first mobile application. I want to trigger an action without clicking a button.
this is the code :

```
  IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                    characteristic.isNotifying
                        ? Icons.sync_disabled
                        : Icons.sync,
                    color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color?.withOpacity(0.5)),
                onPressed: onNotificationPressed,
              )
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: when do you want to trigger the action? on load?

Comment: I want to trigger the action when I open the screen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something on *'on pressed'* just make a void function and call the function in '`initState`' and here you go.

You can also manage the conditions when, how or why the function should run.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SomePage> createState() => _SomePageState();
}

class _SomePageState extends State<SomePage> {
void yourfunction(){
 all the functionalities you want on your button press`enter code here`
}
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   yourfunction();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
                characteristic.isNotifying
                ? Icons.sync_disabled
                : Icons.sync,
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color?.withOpacity(0.5)
            ),
            onPressed: yourfunction();
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to press the button, I want to do my work without pressing anything

Comment: Brother that is why I'm asking you to make an individual function and then call the function in 'initState'. Every function in inItState runs automatically without pressing the button every time you open the page inItState run your functions automatically. let me know if you have questions. if you do not have any questions than accept the answer

Comment: But I'm using stateless widget

Comment: @rania just click on the stateless widget and look at the left side of the screen you see a bulb. click on it and convert it to state full class. hopefully, it's clear now. you can accept the answer if you have any question you can ask me

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and just call it on build

Example:

```
onNotificationPressed(){
  //... do something
}

onNotificationPressed();
```

Complete sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp( home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter - How to trigger a button action without pressing it with flutter?';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  
  bool isNotifying = true;
  
  void onNotificationPressed(){
    setState(() { isNotifying = !isNotifying; });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    onNotificationPressed();
 
    return IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
                isNotifying
                    ? Icons.sync_disabled
                    : Icons.sync,
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color?.withOpacity(0.5)),
            onPressed: onNotificationPressed,
          );  
  }
}
```

You can paste the **complete sample** on [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?)

Comment: actually   onNotificationPressed is a VoidCallBack  : ` final VoidCallback? onNotificationPressed;`